# MSTest - Ignore some tests by default

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, mstest

I have some Tests which I want to NOT run by default (on **dotnet test** command)

Those tests should be run only if some parameter is set explicitly by environment var or some other filter like test categories.

This project has unit tests (SomeTests) as well as some tests that have external dependencies (SomeTests2). So I want to run SomeTests2 only when some parameter is set.

There are multiple unit test projects in the solution and none of them have categories defined. So I can only do a "dotnet test" on the solution to run all the tests, and at that time I want to ignore the SomeTests2

```
[TestClass] //Always Run
Class SomeTests 
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void test1(){}
}

[TestClass] //Run ONLY if some parameter is set (eg. environment var or some other param)
Class SomeTests2
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void test1(){}

    [TestMethod]
    public void test1(){}
}
```

I know the ideal way is to split them into multiple test projects but is there any other way to do this without splitting it ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests?pivots=mstest

Seems to be possible to tag your tests with both priority and category, and then run them from command line with parameters.

Comment: then i have to categorize the tests in all the other projects that are part of the solution